# Laravel 7 Trying to access array offset on value of type null", exception: "ErrorException"

Tags: php, laravel

I'am using Laravel with Vuejs. I present the following query, which shows me the products, but at the moment of consulting the pagination it gives me the following error: "Trying to access array offset on value of type null", exception: "ErrorException"

My query:

```
$pagination = $request->query('pagination');
        $prod = Product::where('is_active', true)
            ->with(['categories', 'brand', 'images' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('default', true);
            }])
            ->Order($request)
            ->BrandStore($request)
            ->CategoryStore($request, $active_categories)
            ->paginate($request['pagination']['per_page'], ['*'], 'page', $pagination['page']);
```

the error gives me in:
`->paginate($request['pagination']['per_page'], ['*'], 'page', $pagination['page'])`;

Comment: Either `$request['pagination']` is null, or `$pagination` is null. You'll need to figure out which one. `Log::info($request['pagination']); Log::info($pagination);` should help you find out which one it is

Comment: @aynber $pagination = $request->query('pagination');
dd($request['pagination'], $pagination); The result is :

$request['pagination'] is []
$pagination is null

Comment: `$pagination` is null, therefore `$pagination['page']` will not work. You'll probably want to add a default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pagination = $request->pagination;
dd($pagination);
```

if it has correct values - use it. Otherwise specify default values

```
->paginate(Arr::get($pagination, 'per_page', 60), ['*'], 'page', Arr::get($pagination, 'page', 1))
```